# How place components on the middle grid in GridLayout Manager?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, grid-layout

I making a clock application but I can't seem to get the clock to be in the middle of the Window(No matter the size of the window). I'm considering using the `GridLayout` Manager but I don't know how to place it in the middle Grid. I have searched StackOverFlow and it seems like no one has the answer to this. I'd appreciate the help.

```
public ClockGUI()
{
    thread = new Thread(this);
    timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    mainPanel();
    setup();
    thread.start();
}
private void mainPanel()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    digitalDisplay = new JLabel(timeFormat);
    digitalDisplay.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 100));
    digitalDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
    digitalDisplay.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    startBut = new JButton("Start");

    mainPanel.add(digitalDisplay);
    mainPanel.add(startBut);
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
private void setup()
{
    this.setTitle("Clock");
    this.add(mainPanel);
    this.setSize(600, 300);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
@Override
public void run()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        digitalDisplay.setText(timeFormat);
        mainPanel.removeAll();
        mainPanel.validate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
        mainPanel.add(digitalDisplay);
        mainPanel.validate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new ClockGUI();
}
}
```

Comment: *"get the clock to be in the middle of the Window"* Add it as the only component, to a `GridBagLayout`. It will be centered within the panel with the GBL. BTW - For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Oh thank you very much it works!